# Replacing text string on Squarespace commerce

Tags: jquery, css, squarespace

I'm doing a rush job as a favour for some friends who needed a site pronto! Therefore I used Squarespace, and have done a partial use of Squarespace commerce, as it's ready-made to do most of what they want. However, being a retailer of expensive products (cars), they often have products which are POA. Currently, Squarespace will not let me create a product without a price.

The test site is at: https://james-wiseman-txkg.squarespace.com/shop/

I've used CSS hacks to create some of the other formatting (Change of currency symbol etc) which I need. Is there any way for me to do a search/replace by CSS or JQuery, which would just act upon a price of $0.00 (or £0.00) and replace it with the text 'POA'?

Have seen other solutions on here using CSS and JQuery/javascript, but ont sure how I do this with a particular string rather than DIV CLASS or TD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as a search pattern, something like:
    `replace(/^[£|$$][ ]?0.00/g,'POA')`